# Running C Program in Cygwin doesn't generate any outcome

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, exe

While writing a simple C Program i encountered the problem that "printf" doesn't generate any outcome. Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

Cygwin log after compiling and running:

```
MMGV@Philipp /cygdrive/c/users/MMGV/Desktop/Programme
$ gcc test.c -o test.exe

MMGV@Philipp /cygdrive/c/users/MMGV/Desktop/Programme
$ test.exe

MMGV@Philipp /cygdrive/c/users/MMGV/Desktop/Programme
$
```

No error message, simply nothing. Opening the generated .exe in the Windows GUI does not work either.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: try adding `\n` after your message. Buffers may not be flushed if no end of line.

Comment: did not work :/

Comment: A newline should be there in any case. If you can confirm that the problem still occurs with the newline, please add it to the code in the question. How exactly did you try to run the program? Did you type something like `./hello` at a shell prompt? Did you double-click on the `.exe` file in the Windows GUI?

Comment: I do not know about cygwin, but usually in Windows if you run a program with console output it will open the console, print the message, then close the console before you can even know it has happened. Solution: add `getchar()` at the end of the program, or run it *from* a console window.

Comment: "Long story short,"?  I think you rather made a short story long!  "Did not work" is not a helpful diagnostic.  I suggest that you edit your question, remove the unnecessary back story and apologies and other waffle, and post the exact code (including the `\n` advised by Jean-F), the command line you have used to build it, all the compiler output  generated during build, and the command line you have used to run the code - a verbatim log of your entire Cygwin session in short.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to use Cycwin? - Unless you are porting Linux specific code (that used `fork()`, for example) there are few reasons to saddle yourself with the added complexity and deployment issues on a Windows platform.  Consider MinGW-GCC instead, or even Microsoft's free tools if you do not mind about incomplete C99 support and non-existent C11 - you do get the best possible debugger though.

Comment: edited question. honestly, i don't know much about coding apart from C# with unity and some Java. I'll try your suggestions

Comment: 1) cygwin is a linux environment.  linux knows nothing (and recognizes no special extension used on a executable.  2) the output from the compile/link is NOT ready to execute as its' 'mode' does not have the 'execute' bits set. 3) it could be executed via `./test.exe`  or by calling `chmod +x test.exe` then running the program via: `test.exe`.   Note, as you found, this program will not run under the windows os.

Answer (score 2):

Change your program to

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");           // add newline
    getchar();                         // wait for an input (newline)
}
```

Because in Windows, the console window probably closes before you have a chance to see it.

Comment: Does work for the Windows GUI, thanks. But why do i still see nothing in Cygwin?

Comment: cygwin is unknown to me. I just use MSVC from console, not even the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You are not running your program. Cygwin shell by default doesn't have current directory in the path. `test.exe` is resolved to a standard Unix-like utility (try `which test`). You need to specify current directory explicity:

```
$./test.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  printf("Hello World.\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

cmd:

```
HP@LAPTOP-VUS0RJO0 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/shri
$ gcc -o first first.c

HP@LAPTOP-VUS0RJO0 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/shri
$ ./first.exe
Hello World.

HP@LAPTOP-VUS0RJO0 /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/shri
$
```